# How to make table truncation query as dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I would like to make the below query as dynamic SQL .

Query 1 : Table Truncation

```
select 'Truncate Table '+''+ name from sys.tables where name like '%RND%'
```

Query 2 :

```
select 'Insert into  '+''+ name +'Select * from '+'.'+''+ name from sys.tables where name like '%RND%'
```

Answer (score 2):

By using the following dynamic query you can truncate the required tables:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL + 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + '; '
FROM sys.tables
WHERE NAME LIKE '%RND%';

--PRINT @DynamicSQL
EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

For the second query the dynamic query is :

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL1 AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @DynamicSQL1 = @DynamicSQL1 + 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + '; '
FROM sys.tables
WHERE NAME LIKE '%RND%';

--PRINT @DynamicSQL1
EXEC (@DynamicSQL1)
```

Comment: Thanks Arul. If possible could you please provide for Query 2

Comment: Great Arul. Your help is highly appreciated unfortunately it showing message window as I am not eligible for vote this answer..

Comment: @SNR: Happy to help. You can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043), if it helps.

Comment: @SNR: Hope not yet accepted the answer. You need to click the RIGHT symbol below the vote count in my answer. It will become Green, then only it consider as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for

All statements are collected in a table, ordered by their point of insert (`id` is `IDENTITY`). It will be - for sure - no problem for you to build your second statement in the same way...

```
DECLARE @cmdTbl TABLE(id INT IDENTITY,cmd NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @cmdTbl(cmd) 
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME) + ';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  AS t
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%RND%'
```

--After collecting all statements I use a `CURSOR` to execute them one after the other.

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT cmd FROM @cmdTbl ORDER BY id;
OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @cmd;
    --EXEC(@cmd); --For syntax check you start without EXEC...
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
vi truncate_count.sql 
use dbname
go
---generate truncate table statements 
select 'Truncate Table '+''+convert(varchar(30),o.name)+'
go' as table_name 
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by table_name
go 

---check the table count 
select 'select count(1) from  '+''+convert(varchar(30),o.name)+'
go' AS table_name
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by table_name
go
```

Step 2:

```
isql -U<USER> -S<server> -P<pwd> -w999 -D<dbname> -e -itruncate_count.sql  -otruncate_count1.sql
```

Step 3:
Add the below lines at the starting of the file truncate_count1.sql

```
use dbname
go 

isql -U<USER> -S<server> -P<pwd> -w999 -D<dbname> -e -itruncate_count1.sql  -otruncate_count1.log
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).